# Firefox reloads webfonts when appending CSS dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, webfonts, fouc

I noticed some strange behavior in Firefox, as I was getting a FOUC when appending CSS by javascript. The problem is, Firefox reloads a webfont each time a CSS style is added dynamically with javascript. Although the reloaded file would normally be cached, it still creates a FOUC (flash of unstyled content).

Actually, the issue ONLY occurs when dynamically adding CSS to a document with `font-family`, or with a `@media` query. In both these cases, Firefox reloads the web font :(

Codepen demonstration:
http://codepen.io/mjau-mjau/pen/XXgZbV?editors=101

As you can see in the image, the webfont is reloaded after applying CSS dynamically:
[image: screen]

This only happens for Firefox. Anyone know why this is happening, or if there is an official bug tracker on this for Firefox?

Comment: yeah no my firefox (43.0.4 and 45 - both are 64bit versions on Windows 7 64bit) does not exhibit that incorrect behaviour

Comment: Using your pen, I don't get the issue in FF on mac osx yosemite.

Comment: Thanks for checking. Must be something local ...